# Adobe Analytics - Custom product level dimensions

Tags: adobe-analytics

I have a question about Adobe Analytics.

I mainly work with Google Analytics and I wonder is there an equivalent to product level custom dimensions in Adobe?

For example, I want to capture extra information about the product such as supplier ID or color, how will I be able to do so in Adobe Analytics?

The only thing I found is merchandising evars, but from the documentation I am not sure if it will work as it is information specific to each product.

I can simply use a evar for this when the purchase is only 1 product, but when the purchase has multiple products, how can I capture extra product information?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use merchandising eVar for this. Make sure when you configure the eVar within the Adobe Analytics interface, to enable it as a merchandising eVar, and set it as **Product Syntax**. Then in your code, populate it within the `s.products` string on a product level.

**Example:**

```
s.products=";prodsku1;;;;evar1=red,;prodsku2;;;;evar1=blue";
```

An alternative common practice is to create SAINT classifications for the product id/sku (e.g. `prodsku1`, above), and upload the meta data to Adobe Analytics via FTP or API endpoint with a separate server-side process.

Comment: Will it still work if I use merch evar in the product string, ,but for evar1 I do not enable merch evar in report suite?

Comment: @Kenny no. The AA config must match the code syntax or AA will ignore values sent in. If you want to have a product level eVar, you must populate it in the products variable, and you must configure it in AA to be a merch eVar product syntax. p.s. - `eVar1` was just an example. You can configure any `eVar[n]` to be a merch eVar. I'm a bit confused why you would even ask this question? Are you unable to change the interface config?